# Android InAppBilling - How do I check if a product was purchased from another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

I implemented successfully In App Billing using the [InAppBilling-V3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library.

I have implemented all of the in app billing within my `ProActivity`, once a purchase is completed successfully I set a boolean value in the shared preferences to `true`.

I know that shared preferences are easily modifiable by the user, so I was looking for a way to double check from my `MainActivity` if the product was purchased.

I would need basically to call

```
billingProcessor.listOwnedProducts()
```

and check that the list is != 0, but I need to do it from my `MainActivity` which is not the one I implemented in app billing in.

Is there a way to achieve that? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. All of the docs do it from the activity where the in app billing is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right the boolean in shared preferences is unsafe and you will have to check in each activity that needs to take a decision upon billing status.

Two potential ways I'd do this.

- Create an Application class and add a function to return whether an
  item is purchased and call this function from both your `ProActivity` and `MainActivity` classes.
- Create a base Activity class with the function
  and then inherit from this class for both your `ProActivity` and
  `MainActivity` classes.

I prefer the second option of creating a base class but that's subjective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean for Application class exactly?

Comment: A class that runs on application startup and is available globally. 
 https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check it out and let you know :)

Comment: I have successfully implemented the second method you suggested, thanks a lot!